# php array issue with break array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I got an Array:

```
$myArrays = array(5,4,3,2,1);

foreach($myArrays as $myArray)
{
  echo $myArray;

  $val = 3;

  if($myArray == $val)
  {
     break;
  }

}
```

Output: 5,4,3

I would want it to be like

output: 3,2,1

is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and there are dozens of ways to do it

Comment: What's the algorithm here? Is the array always in order?

Comment: @MarkBaker please do tell

Comment: Example: `$myArrays = array(5,4,3,2,1);

$val = 3;

foreach(array_slice($myArrays,array_search($val,$myArrays)) as $myArray)
{
  echo $myArray;
}`

Comment: @JonStirling Yes its always in order

Comment: @MarkBaker you did it in one line, cool. thank you. kindly post you answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following snippet. 
The first element of array is always the left one, when you define it.

```
<?php

foreach($myArrays as $myArray)
{
  if ($myArray <= 3) {
    echo $myArray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArrays = array(5,4,3,2,1);

foreach($myArrays as $myArray)
{

  $val = 3;

  if($myArray > $val)
  {
     continue;
  }
  echo $myArray;

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a `boolean` variable outside loop to keep track of wheter you got the element you're looking for.

Skip the loop (By using `continue` keyword) until you find that element.

So your will look something like this,

```
$foundelement=false;
foreach($myArrays as $myArray)
{
  $val = 3;
  if(!$foundelement && $myArray != $val)
  {
     continue;
  } else {
     $foundelement=true;
  }
  if($foundelement) {
      echo $myArray;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/620081